# Scheduling parameterized reports in Crystal Reports Server

Tags: crystal-reports, scheduling, parameterized, crystal-reports-server

I'm trying to set up a report to run monthly in Crystal Reports Server 2008 that will give me the next month's Affordable Care Plan termination dates. However, as far as I can tell, I can only give it a particular date string, not "7 days after the report is scheduled". How do I do this? (Same question for CR2008, actually, but the server is the one I'm interested in right now.)

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with a Crystal Reports add-on called Report Runner Batch. http://www.crystalscheduler.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the answer to this involves CR2008's new feature, optional parameters. If the HasValue({?MyParameter}) function returns false, you can use the default: otherwise, use the value of MyParameter.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into rePORTAL at reportalsoftware.com. It allows you to schedule your reports with dynamic date parameters (for example, currentdate + 7D) and point to the same copy of the report for on demand web access.